# ¿Por qué no funciona el contador?

Tags: variables, shell, contador

Mi código:

```
#! /bin/bash
contador = 0
while :
do
        echo -n "Escriba el nmero:"
        read numero
        case $numero in
        (""|*[^0-9]*) printf "\nError: [numero] no es un caracter valido\n";;
        (*) printf "\nEl primer digito es: ${numero:0:1}";;
        esac
        echo -n "Si quiere volver a intentarlo presione 1, de lo contrario presiona cualquier otra cosa"
        read volver
        if [[ $volver != 1 ]]
        then
             echo "El nmero de vces usado fue $contador"
             echo "Adios"
             sleep 2
             break
        fi
        contador = contador + 1
done
```

Al ejecutarlo me dice:

> line 26: contador: not found.

Creí que por defecto valía 0 y por eso al principio lo hice sin definir el contador fuera del while. Como no sirvió lo definí afuera pero nada, sigue ssaliendo lo mismo, el contador lo tenía arriba y lo pasé al final del while pero nada, igual.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La asignación no puede llevar espacios alrededor del igual, es decir, la línea 2 debe ser:

```
contador=0
```

Y por otro lado, la línea en la que intentas incrementar el contador tiene varios problemas. De un lado, otra vez los espacios alrededor del igual. De otro lado, a la derecha debes usar  `$contador` en lugar de `contador` para obtener el valor que tenía, pero finalmente, lo más importante de todo, el lenguaje de *shell* no es un lenguaje de programación, sino de ejecución de comandos, y tiende a considerar los valores de las variables como cadenas en vez de números. La línea:

```
contador=$contador+1
```

no producirá el resultado esperado, sino que, si por ejemplo el bucle se ejecuta tres veces, al final `$contador` valdrá `0+1+1` (como cadena).

Para cálculos matemáticos debes usar `let` con una sintaxis como la siguiente:

```
let "contador = $contador + 1"
```

Fíjate que a `let` le pasas una cadena (todo entre comillas), pero el `$contador` será expandido a su valor dentro de las comillas, por lo que `let` verá algo como `contador = 0 + 1` en la primera iteración, y evaluará matemáticamente la expresión, que le dará `1` como resultado, y lo asignará a `contador`. Cuando usas `let`, al ir entre comillas la expresión, puedes usar los espacios con más libertad.

Comment: Gracias crack, con esas explicaciones entendí perfecto lo que me faltaba.